# Extracting specific number of records so that certain overall conditions are met

Tags: sql, oracle

Here I describe an abstract case, but it's similar to the one I'm now trying to solve. I know how I can obtain a rough result with a PL/SQL block, but I wonder if someone could suggest a solution with a single select query.

Suppose we have a table `t_people` with thousands of records describing some group of people with the following set of attributes:

- `id`
- `age`, number
- `height` in cm, number
- `gender`, varchar2 ('male' or 'female')

And we need to extract N records so that the result set meets the following conditions:

- 30% of selected people are higher than 180 cm
- 60% of selected people are male
- 40% of selected people are older then 40

We may also assume that N is much less than the total number of rows in the table and the problem is solvable.

How would you suggest doing this with a single select query?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use a UNION ALL of 8 queries - the first returning N*.3*.6*.4 people who are higher than 180 cm, male, over 40, the next returning N*.3*.6*.6 people who are higher than 180 cm, male, under 40, and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would stratify the data into 8 groups and then take proportional samples from each group to meet your requirements.  One crude method is to convert the conditions to groups, say:

- 300 people taller than 180, not male, not older
- 100 people shorter, not male, not older
- 400 people shorter, male, older
- 200 people shorter, male, not older

Then you can tackle this as:

```
with p as (
      select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by height, male, age order by height) as seqnum
      from (select p.*,
                   (case when height > 180 then 1 else 0 end) as height,
                   (case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as male,
                   (case when age > 40 then 1 else 0 end) as age
            from people p
           ) p
     )
select p.*
from p
where (height = 1 and male = 0 and age = 0 and seqnum <= 300) or
      (height = 0 and male = 0 and age = 0 and seqnum <= 100) or
      (height = 0 and male = 1 and age = 1 and seqnum <= 400) or
      (height = 0 and male = 1 and age = 0 and seqnum <= 200);
```

There is another method that you can use where you fill the 8 buckets evenly, keeping track of the numbers along each dimension (younger/older, male/female, shorter/taller).  Then you stop filling when the first dimension is filled and continue filling with the 4 complementary cells.  Repeat the process until you have the desired numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your first method would suit me good. Although in my real case I have 9 grouping attributes, I think your idea is still appilcable there. As for the second method, I thought about something like that but slightly different. First, I was going to select N rows randomly and look at the proportions. While the proportions are not good enough, I'd replace bad records with better ones from the remaining set one by one. The record is better if it makes the set closer to the desired proportions. Again, thanks a lot and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally chosen the first approach [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945653/4314439) by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) with some minor amendments. I've kept the original idea but also introduced several additional subqueries to specify the desired distribution of records within groups and built a matrix with desired record counts per group. There's also global params section which contains the only parameter to specify the overall record count.

The query produces quite useful results:

```
with 
    people as (
        select  id,
                floor(months_between(sysdate, date_birth)/12) age,
                195 - least(floor(months_between(sysdate, date_birth)/12), 50) height,
                decode(sex, 1, 'male', 'female') gender
        from    my_people_table
        where   date_birth is not null and rownum < 100000
    ),
    params as ( /* Global params */
        select  100 rec_count   -- total record count 
        from dual
    ),
    age_groups as (     /* distribution by height */
        select  'group 1' age_group, .7 prc from dual union
        select  'group 2' age_group, .3 prc from dual  
    ),
    height_groups as ( /* distribution by height */
        select  'group 1' height_group, .6 prc from dual union
        select  'group 2' height_group, .4 prc from dual  
    ),
    genders as (       /* distribution by gender */
        select  'male'   gender, .6 prc from dual union
        select  'female' gender, .4 prc from dual  
    ),
    mx as (            /* a matrix with record counts per group */
        select  age_group, height_group, gender,
                ceil(
                    age_groups.prc * 
                    height_groups.prc * 
                    genders.prc * 
                    rec_count
                )  rec_count       
        from    age_groups, height_groups, genders, params
    ),
    xpeople as (       /* Minor transformations - groups and group counters */
        select  p.*, 
                row_number() over (
                    partition by age_group, height_group, gender
                        order by age_group, height_group, gender
                ) rec_num
        from (                             
                select  people.*,
                        case 
                            when age    <=  40 then 'group 1' 
                                               else 'group 2' 
                        end age_group,
                        case 
                            when height <= 180 then 'group 1' 
                                               else 'group 2' 
                        end height_group
                from    people
        ) p
    )
/* the resulting query uses the matrix to filter the records */    
select  xpeople.*
from    xpeople join mx 
            on  xpeople.age_group = mx.age_group 
            and xpeople.height_group = mx.height_group      
            and xpeople.gender = mx.gender
            and xpeople.rec_num <= mx.rec_count
```

Thanks for the help!